# Advisors asked for a complete draft of the thesis - should I include the acknowledgement?

Tags: etiquette, acknowledgement

I have written an acknowledgement in my PhD thesis thanking my advisors. Meanwhile they have asked for a draft of the thesis (before I submit it). Can I include the acknowledgment in the draft or will it be awkward for them to read my appreciation? I am also afraid that they might comment on it, causing me to change it.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem unless the acknowledgment were in poor taste.

Comment: At our university there is a rule that forbids acknowledgements in the submitted, graded version and they are only allowed in the final, published version, so you should check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different universities may have different rules on this. At my university, there is no policy that prevents including it with the draft.

Can you include it?  Yes, unless there's a local policy in place.

Should you?  Up to you. I didn't - I didn't include the Acknowledgements until the final version (which they still see and approve).